# Zend Form not working properly, can't understand the concept of documentation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am new born to zend. Was going through zend form documentation and couldn't understand one things. having a project on zend with oracle so my life is already messed up ;-) . I was stucked in a few basic problem of Zend_Form class. The problem is: when we are setting up a form in action and it is posted back to that action only, obviously new form object will get created and my posted value will get disappeared like smoke. So how to keep them alive. I got a substitute of `$this->getrequest()->getparams()` but in zend documentation and where ever I saw for examples they all have same flow. They are not using `getparams()` as option. Let me take it through code, to get very clear idea.

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->title = 'Welcome to CashTray ';       // passing title to view
        // creating cashtray mapper object
        $cashTrayMapper = new Application_Model_CashtrayMapper();

        // search form object
/* It will reset the object, a obvious thing*/
            $searchForm = new Application_Form_Cashtray_Search();                       // creating search form object

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())                                          // post request found
        {
            var_dump($searchForm->getValues(), $this->getRequest()->getparams());die;                
        }
        else
        {

            $this->view->form = $searchForm;
            // retrieving cashtray list
            $this->view->entries = $cashTrayMapper->fetchAll();                               // passing form to view
        }


    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(2) { ["client"]=> string(0) "" ["offset"]=> string(0) "" } 

array(6) { ["controller"]=> string(8) "cashtray" ["action"]=> string(5) "index" ["module"]=> string(7) "default" ["client"]=> string(4) "1001" ["offset"]=> string(3) "214" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Search" }
```

Now we can see that form is posted, values are there but why I can't get it through `$searchForm->getValues();` In examples they are having `$form` instead of `$searchForm` which I don't think should be the problem.

Comment: The request object in ZF, as you have noticed provides different ways to acces values. `->getParams()` pulls values from `setParam()`,`$_GET` & `$_POST` in that order. `->getPost()` just pulls from `$_POST` and `getQuery()` from `$_GET`. none of these values are filtered. Filtered and validated form data is accessed with the `$form->getValues()` or `$form->getValue('name_0f_value');` after calling `->isValid($data)`.

Comment: thanks rocky.I implemented it in the way answers are given but may I know why is it so? because when I accessed it just above isValid() it was giving empty valued result and when I accessed it after/inside isValid() it showed all values correctly.Why??

Comment: because until you call `->isValid` against the form object the `getValues()` array is empty. It's not filled until validation and filtering is applied by calling `->isValid`. The raw values are always available by calling `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` However these values are not validated and are unfiltered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical workflow would be something more like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->title = 'Welcome to CashTray ';       // passing title to view
    // creating cashtray mapper object
    $cashTrayMapper = new Application_Model_CashtrayMapper();

    // search form object
    $searchForm = new Application_Form_Cashtray_Search();                       // creating search form object

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($searchForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            // do stuff and then redirect
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $searchForm;

    // retrieving cashtray list
    $this->view->entries = $cashTrayMapper->fetchAll();
}
```

that way if the form validation fails, the data is still in the form object and will be redisplayed along with the relevant errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load (and validate) the values in Zend_Form with $searchForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()).

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, calling `$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())` populates your form with POST data, also filtering the values with filters and adding errors if validation rules are not met.

What I'd like to add is that you can also set the form values by calling `$form->populate($data)` where `$data` is an array with names matching your input names. This is handy if you have forms for editing existing entities and you want to pre-populate them. This does not perform any checks with validators, unlike `isValid()`.

Comment: thanks for your supports as it was too an issue I was facing..but YESTERDAY.. :)